# button doesn't change colours

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

i just started using tkinter for a school project.
my idea here is that when the button is clicked the state variable changes and goes through a loop of four states where each state has its own colour to indicate visually which state the button is in, but here where the problem shows. when i run the code, the button is there but doesn't change colours when clicked.

```
from tkinter import *
#states of the squares are empty(white),road(grey),intial point(green),finish point(red)
def click():
    state=0
    state=+1
    if (state%4)==0:
        return'black'
    elif (state%4)==1:
        return'grey'
    elif (state%4)==2:
        return'green'
    else:
        return'red'
    

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Exemple")
icon = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
window.iconphoto(True,icon)
window.config(background='#26282b')
background= click()
button = Button(window,text='            ',
                command=click(),
                background=background)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command=click()` should be `command=click`. You're running the function when you create the button, not when the click happens.

Comment: state = 0  move state variable outside the function and get global variable in function (like  global state)

Comment: `state=+1` should be `state += 1`

Comment: The return value of the `command` function isn't used for anything. It doesn't become the button color. If you want to change the button's color, you need to call `button.configure()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistakes in your attached code:

- You used `state = 0` inside `click()`, so every time it enters the function, it defines `state` as `0`.
- You used `state = +1` which is the same as `state = 1` which always set `state` to 1.
- `command` doesn't use the returned value for anything; it will not automatically change the background color. You have to write the logic yourself using `config`.
- You used `command=click()`, which calls the function and returns a string. It won't call to `click` function when you press the button. For that, you need to pass a **pointer** to that function.

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
from tkinter import *
state=0 # ---> define state outside of the function
def click():
    global state

    state+=1 # ---> Replaced =+1 with += 1  
    if (state%4)==0:
        return'black'
    elif (state%4)==1:
        return'grey'
    elif (state%4)==2:
        return'green'
    else:
        return'red'
    

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Exemple")
icon = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
window.iconphoto(True,icon)
window.config(background='#26282b')
background= click()
button = Button(window,text=' '*12, background=background)
button.config(command = lambda: button.config(background=click())) # ---> Changed the command to a lambda function that uses button.config to config the button's bg color
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

You can also adjust your `click()` function:

```
from tkinter import *
state=0 # ---> define state outside of the function
def click():
    global state
    state+=1 # ---> Replaced =+1 with += 1  
    if (state%4)==0:
        color = 'black'
    elif (state%4)==1:
        color = 'grey'
    elif (state%4)==2:
        color = 'green'
    else:
        color = 'red'
    button.config(background=color)
    

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Exemple")
icon = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
window.iconphoto(True,icon)
window.config(background='#26282b')
button = Button(window,text=' '*12, command=click)
click()
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

---

If you choose to use the first function, you should consider replacing the name of the function to something more clear, such as `get_color`.

It makes the code easier to understand, and using meaningful names is always a good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can change `state` variable and according that change color of the button:

```py
from tkinter import *

state = 0


def state_to_color(state):
    color = "red"

    if state == 0:
        color = "black"
    elif state == 1:
        color = "grey"
    elif state == 2:
        color = "green"

    return color


# states of the squares are empty(white),road(grey),intial point(green),finish point(red)
def click():
    global state

    state = (state + 1) % 4

    button.configure(
        background=state_to_color(state), activebackground=state_to_color(state)
    )


window = Tk()


window.geometry("100x100")
window.title("Exemple")
window.config(background="#26282b")
button = Button(
    window,
    text="    ",
    command=click,
    background=state_to_color(state),
    activebackground=state_to_color(state),
)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Creates this app:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers, I would suggest to create a *cycle list of colors* using `itertools.cycle()` function and then get the *next color* using `next()` function.

```py
from itertools import cycle
...

# create the cycle list of colors
# should the first color be white instead of black according to the comment in your code?
colors = cycle(['black', 'grey', 'green', 'red'])

def click():
    button.config(background=next(colors))

...

button = Button(window, width=12, background=next(colors), command=click)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to use match case statement without nesting `if/else`and without adding namespace.

Remove brace bracket, should be `command=click`

Snippet:

```
def state_to_color(state):
     
    match state:
        case 0:     
            color = "black"
        case 1:
            color = "grey"
        case 2:
            color = "green"            
        case _:
             color = "red"
    return color
```